# Node.js and server process

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

assume a node js file should work with `USERS` Objects which contains a list of `user object`. each user is a json object with 20-30 property in it.
And also there are 10,000 users connecting to server simultaneously.
and 2000 of these users are chatting. So for each message:

1. server should look to this `USERS` global object.
2. search in 10.000 users and also search in 30 property of specific user for some reason. permission and etc. [ or may be connect to mysql ]
3. and finally emit to that specific user.

with All these steps and process. node js will slow down? or even go down?!

and finally how many simultaneous connect can nodejs handle ?

Comment: if you are not good enought to answer this question, do not vote down please. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't actually know without testing, the only limitation is set by system performance & resources, then the performance of the software.

Depending on node.js requirements which are low and the high performance code in it, you can pretty much support your application without a high end system.

You should try to build, the skeleton of your application, and test performance.